# How do I automatically update the value of a variable when a data is changed in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to get total price of the orders made that I have stored in an array. The code looks something like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Config } from '../config';
var ordersArray = [

];
@Component({
  selector: 'orders-page',
  templateUrl : 'orders.html'
})

export class Orders{
  public orders = ordersArray;
  public config = new Config;
  public addOrder(item){
    ordersArray.push(item);
  }
  public clearOrders(){
    var length = this.orders.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
      ordersArray.pop();
    }
  }
  public total = this.getPrice();
  public getPrice(){
    let price = 0;
    for(let order of ordersArray){
      price = (parseInt(order.item.price) * parseInt(order.quantity) ) + price;
    }
    return price;
  }
  public clearOrder(order){
    for(let i = 0;i < this.orders.length;i++){
      if(order.title == this.orders[i].title){
        ordersArray.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the template, I have `{{total}}`.
Now, when I remove an element from the `ordersArray`, I want the `{{total}}` to automatically update. How do I do that ?

Comment: while removing the orders just calculate the price again by iteration and set it in this.price. {{price}} in HTML will be automatically update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `getPrice()` after updating the `ordersArray`, So call `getPrice()` inside the `clearOrder()`

Try this

```
public clearOrder(order){
    for(let i = 0;i < this.orders.length;i++){
      if(order.title == this.orders[i].title){
        ordersArray.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
    this.total = this.getPrice(); 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!! Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `getPrice()` function every time `price` is concerned.
For example, when you add a new order, when you delete one order, when you delete them all...

I think you can improve some code:

```
  public clearOrders(){
    ordersArray = ordersArray[];
  }
```

And I can't see why you wrote `public orders = ordersArray;` but afterwards you are using `ordersArray`.

Be careful because you are mixing `ordersArray` and `orders` within the `ordersArray()` function, and I think you should be only using one.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you :) I did the ordersArray thing because I am storing the orders in a different array so that It wouldn't be affected when a new instance of the class is called and I need to access the ordersArray from some other instance of the class. I'm sure I'm not going to get confused because of this.